# form runat Tag causes Redirect to same page

Tags: javascript, html, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have run into a very weird situation. I have two pages `Default.aspx` and `Registration.aspx` . Initially Default page is loaded. There is a button on `Default.aspx`, a javascript function is triggered when user clicks on this button and in JS function I am simply redirecting him to second page using `window.location` .

If I include `form runat="server"` tag in Default.aspx page, redirect does not happen. Instead it redirects to same page i.e Default.aspx after user clicks on button. But if I remove `form runat="server"` tag from Default page then its working fine.

Following is the code of `Default.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Temp_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

<script src="script/Script_Default_Page.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<form runat="server">
<div class="headerContainer">
    <div class="header_wraper">
        <div class="Headernav">
            <a href="#">Contact us</a>
            <a href="#">FAQ</a>
            <a href="#">Projects</a>
            <a href="#">About us</a>
            <a href="#" class="select">Home</a>
            <br clear="all" />
            Welcome
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="float_left"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Pakistan" /></a>
        <br clear="all" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sliderContainer">
    <div class="sliderWraper">
        <img src="images/slider_img.jpg" class="float_right" alt="" />
        <div class="sliderText">
            <h1>
            <div class="sliderBtns">
                <a href="#" class="select"></a>
                <a href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"></a>
                <br clear="all" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br clear="all" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="postContainer">
    <div class="postWraper">
        <div class="postBox">
            <div class="postText">
                <b>Maryam Aminah</b>
                <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. </p>
            </div>
            <img src="images/post_img1.png" alt="" />
            <br clear="all" />
        </div>
        <div class="postBox">
            <div class="postText">
                <b>Asad Khawaja</b>
                <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. </p>
            </div>
            <img src="images/post_img2.png" alt="" />
            <br clear="all" />
        </div>
        <div class="postBox border_non margin_r_zero">
            <div class="postText">
                <b>Sonia Waqas</b>
                <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. </p>
            </div>
            <img src="images/post_img3.png" alt="" />
            <br clear="all" />
        </div>
        <br clear="all" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom_Container">
    <div class="rightSide">
        <div class="searchBox">
            <a href="#" class="SearchBtn" ><img src="images/search_btn.png" alt="" /></a>
            <input type="text" class="SearchTextBox" value="Search Profiles..." />
        </div>
        <button id="ReserveSpaceBtn" class="reservebtn" onclick="showdiv('popup');">Reserve Space</button>
      <div class="postInfo">
            <div class="postInfoName">
                <img src="images/Aseer_img1.png" alt="" />
                <b>Asser Malik</b>
                <br clear="all" />
            </div>
            <div class="mamngmnt">
                Management Trainee - Commercial at <b>Coca-Cola Beverages, Pakistan</b>
            </div>
            <div class="mamngmnt study">
                Studied at <b>Lahore University of Management Sciences</b>
            </div>
            <div class="mamngmnt location">Lives in <b>Lahore, Pakistan</b></div>
            <input type="text" class="aboutPakistan" value="About Pakistan" />
            <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. </p>
            <p><a href="#"><img src="images/back_btn.png" alt="" /></a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="map">   
        <span><img src="images/map.png" alt="" /></span>
        <div class="footer">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/brand1.png" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/brand2.png" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/brand3.png" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/brand4.png" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/brand5.png" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/brand6.png" alt="" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/brand7.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="addBox">
        <b>Global Stats*</b>
        <span><img src="images/down_img.png" alt="" /></span>
        <span><img src="images/loader.png" alt="" /></span>
        <b>Project Milestones</b>
        <span><img src="images/down_img.png" alt="" /></span>
        <span><img src="images/add_img.png" alt="" /></span>
        <b>Goal:</b>
        <p>Teach 20 Children</p>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

This is JS function definition which triggers on button click:

```
function showdiv(id) {
window.location = "Registration.aspx";
}
```

Can anyone point out where the issue resides? This is the first time I have encountered this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What is Temp_Default?

Comment: I have created these files in a Temp directory then I moved them here. But its not due to this value because I have created a new Default file and same problem persists there too...

Comment: Solved this problem by doing Redirect operation through server sided function instead in JS.

Comment: OK. But in case you still want to know what caused it, you could test if the button also submitted the form, in addition to changing the location. Buttons have `type="submit"` by default, so it could have been that it tried to do those two actions at once.

Comment: @Nida: If you have solved this problem you should add your solution as an answer and accept it so that the system can mark the question as answered.